# How to take screenshot after every interaction with page? Java, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to take screenshot after every interaction with page (clicks, scrolls etc)
How can i do that? I use Selenium and Java.

Comment: browser = Googe Chrome

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that shows how to take a screenshot using Selenium and Java.

You can use the takeSnapshot functino wherever you need it:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Guru99TakeScreenshot {

    @Test

    public void testGuru99TakeScreenShot() throws Exception{

        WebDriver driver ;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //goto url

        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");

        //Call take screenshot function

        this.takeSnapShot(driver, "c://test.png") ;     

    }

    /**

     * This function will take screenshot

     * @param webdriver

     * @param fileWithPath

     * @throws Exception

     */

    public static void takeSnapShot(WebDriver webdriver,String fileWithPath) throws Exception{

        //Convert web driver object to TakeScreenshot

        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);

        //Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file

                File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            //Move image file to new destination

                File DestFile=new File(fileWithPath);

                //Copy file at destination

                FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);

    }

}
```

[Source](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium 3 ,You could use WebDriverEventListener Interface provided in Selenium, add implementation for the actions after which you need screenshot

[WebDriverEventListener](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html)

It has multiple methods that you can implement and add a method to take screenshot after every action that you want it to

```
@Override
    public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver webDriver) {
        takeSnapShot(driver, filepaht);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver webDriver) {
                takeSnapShot(webDriver, filepath);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver webDriver) {
                takeSnapShot(webDriver, filepath);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
                takeSnapShot(webDriver, filepath);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, CharSequence[] charSequences) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, CharSequence[] charSequences) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScript(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScript(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterSwitchToWindow(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> outputType) {

    }

    @Override
    public <X> void afterGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> outputType, X x) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeGetText(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterGetText(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, String s) {

    }
```

Write a method to take screenshots like below

```
 public void takeSnapShot(WebDriver webdriver,String fileWithPath) throws Exception{

        //Convert web driver object to TakeScreenshot

        TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);

        //Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file

                File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            //Move image file to new destination

                File DestFile=new File(fileWithPath);

                //Copy file at destination

                FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);

    }
```

Your driver Initialisation should like this where we now use EventFiringWebDriver instead of WebDriver

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
Create an instance of your eventHandler class and register it for events using the register method of EventFiringWebDriver object created above. Here is the code
 EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
 eventDriver.register(handler);
```

For Selenium 4 you can use EventFiringDecorator
[EventFiringDecorator](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringDecorator.html)